# Wrong datetime return

Tags: entity-framework

My database has 5 lines with data:

1. {02/17/2013 00:00:00}
2. {04/15/2013 00:00:00}
3. {06/17/2013 00:00:00}
4. {08/26/2013 00:00:00}
5. {12/30/2013 00:00:00}

but when I do this:

```
_db.Quarter
.Where(q => q.Begin <= DateTime.Now)
.ToList();
```

with DateTime.Now = {04/16/2013 16:02:26}
it returns only one result: {02/17/2013 00:00:00}

My EF version is 4.3.1.

One doubt: DateTime.Now uses the database server clock or the application server clock?

Comment: Your doubt is a good question. Not sure if LINQ query changes "`DateTime.Now()`" into an actual datetime, or into a `GETDATE()`. You'd have to inspect the actual query that's generated by LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but all of those other dates are in the future (`Datetime.Now()` is 11/Apr). I would expect the result you're getting...

Comment: I changed the time  in the clock to simulate it :)

Comment: But shouldn't return the seocnd line too?

Comment: Can you add another date that's definitely before real now? Maybe your `DateTime.Now()` is not what you think it is?

Comment: Or breakpoint on a `var x = DateTime.Now()` and inspect just to ensure

Comment: Yeah, tha's the solution. My database server clock is 04/11/2013 and my application clock is 04/16/2013. So when I use datetime.now directly in the lambda it uses the database clock I guess.

Comment: I suspect that LINQ is actually passing through `GETDATE()` (which will get the dateTime on the server) on the query instead of parsing and passing through a DateTime object. Makes sense, I guess, if there's a possible lag between query being asked and execution on DB server